# Is it bad practice to have the order of an enum declaration matter?

Tags: java, enums

Let's say I have the enum `AccessRole` with 3 declarations:

```
public Enum AccessRole
{
    Admin,
    User,
    ReadOnly;
}
```

I use the ordinal value of this enum to denote the concept of "hierarchical" access role. For example,

```
if (currentRole.ordinal() < otherRole.ordinal())
{
    //We know currentRole has more user rights than otherRole, because it's ordinal is smaller.
}
```

I don't base any rights of the ordinal, but I use the ordinal to sort and compare the enum values when necessary (for example, in the user interface, to sort all possible access roles by ordinal from "many rights" to "limited rights").

This works fine, but I'm concerned that this is not clear. If any other developer were to insert a new accessrole at the bottom of the enum instead of at the correct ordinal, the whole system is messed up.

Is there any way to deal with this? That this, impose an order on enum declarations, yet make it clear in the code semantically that the order is important/being used?

Answer (score 3):

You are rightly concerned. The order of enums is often not considered important by developers.

Yet adding another artifical ordinal just make things worse, because now you have take care that the numbers are different, and the meaning of the new ordering is still not clear.

I think what would help is to move the check for privileges in the Enum. So have method in your Enum that looks like this:

```
public boolean includes(Role otherRole){
    return (this.ordinal() < otherRole.ordinal())
}
```

Now you can add tests. And every developer worth her money will understand that changing the order of things in the enum is actually a change in business logic.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one. This is great for when the strategy about "when does role X include role Y?" changes from using the ordinal to something else. But this just keeps using ordinal. How does this solve the original problem?

Comment: It puts the use of the ordinal right into the enum, together with the tests, it makes it very obvious that the order of enums is relevant.

Comment: Why do you think adding another ordering is "artifical" and "makes things worse"? I see 2 advantages. First is forcing other developers to enter a value when creating new enums, and this will make them VERY aware of what it means. Second is the added flexibility that the actual source code ordinal is not important. I'm not saying you're wrong! I'm asking you to explain why you think I'm wrong.

Comment: 1. Flexibility that you don't need is a bad thing.

Comment: 2. Now you have two orderings in you enum. Which one is the one used for the hierarchy? Not at all obvious.

Comment: 3. Forcing developers to explicit provide a value, makes it not clear at all what this value is good for. User(23) tells me NOTHING.

Comment: counter to 2: by not having an explicit ordering it is even LESS obvious?
counter to 3: User(23) tells me A WHOLE BOOK, because the enum has a variable called "roleLevel" with the appropiate setter and getter and documentation. This variable is defined right in the source code of the enum itself.

Comment: @user1884155 Please tell me you don't have setters on enums.

Answer (score 2):

While the order of enums is not *normally* considered as being important, the way I would address this case (where it does matter) would be to put a prominent comment in the source code.

Sure, you can't protect against programmers who modify (butcher!) your code without reading the comments.  But on the other hand:

- they are liable to butcher your code in other ways anyway, and
- ultimately, if they ignore your comments and break the code as a result, they should take the blame.

Comment: I agree, though I'd also move the role check into the enum class like proposed by @jens-schauder. Otherwise comments in the enum might easily be missed.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an integer attribute to the Enum and document that it is used for maintaining the hierarchy of roles. This also allows to define two roles at the same level.

Comment: There is no indication that the OP needs multiple elements on the same level, so it really makes the problem worse.

Comment: I don't see any problem with adding the number, they don't have to be the same and they can indeed be used for imposing order apart from the enum declaration order.

Comment: @JensSchauder, I didn't mention it as a requirement, it was more a notice about the side-effect of using an integer attribute.